Parent :host styles affects to :host styles of child

As you can see on picture the app-tracking-elements-table get styles from app-left-menu. I wrote styles in SCSS using :host for both components
I thought that :host is isolated and affects only to hosting element. Is there any way to separate them?
left-menu-component.scss
:host {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 8px;

    position: relative;

    height: 100%;
    width: var(--left-menu-width);
    padding: 12px 0 24px 0;

    background-color: var(--light-100);

    box-shadow: $box-shadow;

    /*Some more styles*/
}

tracking-elements-table.component.scss
:host {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;

    width: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--light-100);

    box-shadow: inset $box-shadow;

    /*Some more styles*/
}

Additional info:



Package
Version




@angular-devkit/architect
0.1802.9


@angular-devkit/build-angular
18.2.9


@angular-devkit/core
18.2.9


@angular-devkit/schematics
18.2.9


@angular/cli
18.2.9


@schematics/angular
18.2.9


rxjs
7.8.1


typescript
5.5.4


zone.js
0.14.10



P.S. If you need more info please ask me and I will add it to question

That's strange. In the DOM you can see that the app-left-menu component has a different host ID than its respective style selector. Did you try restarting the dev server?

@JSONDerulo Of course :) I restarted whole computer) I just noticed that in style tab it show exactly same ng_host as child component so may be scss generates several ng_host styles?

@EzioMercer please share working example on stackblitz or github repo for checking

@NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/EzioMercer/AlphaSmart

You should got to front folder and run npm i && npm start

The problem was due to importing the styles of one component in another. Due to this the :host styles got applied to another component, which was not intended to.
tracking-elements-table.component.scss
@import '../../../core/components/left-menu/left-menu.component'; // <- remove this!

:host {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;

    width: 500px;

You should only share CSS files that have CSS variables and SCSS variables defined in them, it is ok to import them.
But when dealing with angular components, keep the styles separated in their own respective SCSS files.
If you want you can write CSS mixins to reduce the amount of code.

We can move the common variables to the main styles.scss which is shared among all components.
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import 'stryles/reset.css';
@import 'stryles/sizes.css';
@import 'stryles/colors.css';
@import 'stryles/global.css';

:root {
    --switch-position: 5%;
    --hover-bg: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--primary-lightblue) var(--switch-position), var(--primary-extralight) var(--switch-position));
    --selected-bg: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--primary-lightblue) var(--switch-position), var(--primary-deepblue) var(--switch-position));

    --hover-bg-2: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 170, 255, 1) var(--switch-position), rgba(229, 244, 255, 1) var(--switch-position));
    --selected-bg-2: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 170, 255, 1) var(--switch-position), rgba(45, 73, 210, 1) var(--switch-position));

}
$box-shadow: 6px 0 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
 

Github Repo

I just realized and wanted to update my question)) But thanks for taking time and watch my project!

So there is no way to import only varibale from scss file?

@EzioMercer No, you should use separate SCSS files, that contain the variables to import them to multiple other files. Remember the styles property of the component decorator is an array, so it can accept multiple style files.

Good point. Thanks again!
